# calling sizeof in constructor initilizer list in multiple inhertance

Tags: c++

Here we are calling sizeof operator on the derived class WData1. As I know, first base class constructor (Persistent) will be called. Till now WData1 doesn't exist because class Persistent constructor is being called and class Data is waiting for his turn.

*

```
class WData1 : public Persistent, public Data {  
public:  
WData1(float f0 = 0.0, float f1 = 0.0,
float f2 = 0.0) : Data(f0, f1, f2),
Persistent(sizeof(WData1)) {}};
```

*

**My question is how sizeof will behave on derived class which doesn't exist yet?**

Comment: The *class* does exist. And the object exists as well (or it would not be possible to call its constructor), even though it's not fully initialized yet.

Comment: You use `sizeof` with a type, not an object - the result is calculated at compile time

Comment: @Unholy You can use `sizeof` on an object - it gives you the size of the type of the object.

Comment: @UnholySheep Also, the OP is using a type.

Comment: The `sizeof` does not operate, during run-time, a class.  I recommend rethinking your design if you need to use `sizeof` on a desktop application.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how sizeof will behave on derived class which doesn't
>   exist yet?

The class already exists so `sizeof` has no problem with it. `sizeof` is a compile-time construct, all the information it needs it already has when you're compiling.

It is true that the `Persistent` constructor is called before the `WData1` constructor but that doesn't matter since the type information of `WData1` is already known. A constructor call is a run-time construct, `sizeof` isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how sizeof will behave on derived class which doesn't exist yet?

`sizeof(WData1)` is the size of class `WData1` (including parent base `Persistent` and `Data`).

Even if you create

```
struct Derived : WData1
{
    char BigBuffer[1024 * 42];
};
```

`sizeof(WData1)` won't change.

You might be tempted to use `sizeof(*this)`

```
class WData1 : public Persistent, public Data {  
public:  
    WData1(float f0 = 0.0, float f1 = 0.0, float f2 = 0.0)
        : Data(f0, f1, f2),
          Persistent(sizeof(*this))
    {}
};
```

But `sizeof` is compile time and would use static type so `WData1`.

You have to propagate the size from derived class to parent:

```
class WData1 : public Persistent, public Data {  
public:  
    WData1(float f0 = 0.0f,
           float f1 = 0.0f,
           float f2 = 0.0f,
           std::size_t size = size_of(WData1))
        : Data(f0, f1, f2),
          Persistent(size)
    {}
};

struct Derived : WData1
{
    Derived(std::size_t size = size_of(Derived)) : WData1(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, size) {}
    char BigBuffer[1024 * 42];
};
```